# MongoDB Java API ISODate

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to insert a **DateTime** into MongoDB from Java.
Essentially I want the following object:

```
    {
        "_id" : ".....",
        "ts": ISODate(".....")
    }
```

How can I create this from a Java Object with MongoDB API?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it as follows :

```
DBCollection coll = ...
coll.insert(new BasicDBObject("ts", new Date()));
```